# Adding row vector to a new dataframe adds the header names but not the values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as;

```
0        0.1912
1        0.3597
2        0.3597
3        0.3597
4        0.3597
5        0.3597
6        0.2739
7        0.1641
8        0.0776
      .
      .
      .
```

First of all, I am transposing it to be row vector. After that, it looks like this;

```
      0       1       2       3      ...   18933   18934   18935   18936
ecg  0.1912  0.3597  0.3597  0.3597  ...  0.3847  0.3847  0.3847  0.3847
```

So as you see, the index numbers are now column header names. Let's say I have stored the above row vector in a variable named `row_vector`. After this, I want to add this row vector to another dataframe like this;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ecg':[row_vector]}) #ecg is used to be a header name for the row vector
```

When I do that, it is adding the row vector into this new dataframe, but in a wrong way;

```
                                                 ecg
0        0       1       2       3      ...   190...
```

As you see, it added the "header names" of the row vector, not the real values under these header names. I would like to have a result like this;

```
                                                                      ecg
0  0.1912  0.3597  0.3597  0.3597  ...  0.3847  0.3847  0.3847  0.3847 ...
```

So, how can I fix it? Thanks in advance...

Comment: `row_vector.values`?

Comment: Well yeah, the answer is that simple. Thanks.

Comment: I included it as an answer as couldn't find a direct duplicate. Happy to be corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) or [`.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas.Series.to_numpy) (New in version 0.24) methods of the series object to access its values. See an example below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,3,4]})

print(df['A']) # prints indexs and values
```

prints:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

whereas you can just access the values:

```
print(df['A'].to_numpy())
```

prints to screen:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Note, the documentation for `.values` comes with a warning:

> Warning We recommend using Series.array or Series.to_numpy(),
>   depending on whether you need a reference to the underlying data or a
>   NumPy array.

so I would use the `.to_numpy` method.